# Android movie decodestream is null

Tags: android, inputstream, gif, movie

I create object movie from gif file in sdcard. Use decodestream for this. Operation result movie is null. I use also method decodeFile and decodeByteArray.
My code

```
public GifView(Context context, InputStream inputStream) {
    super(context);
    gifInputStream = inputStream;
    init(context);
}

private void init(Context context){
    setFocusable(true);
    gifMovie = Movie.decodeStream(gifInputStream);
    movieWidth = gifMovie.width();
    movieHeight = gifMovie.height();
    movieDuration = gifMovie.duration();
}
```

Comment: Please check with this answer https://github.com/sbakhtiarov/gif-movie-view

Comment: I used this library. I get exception VerifyError. This probably is conflict version api my application and version api library.

Comment: where you able to fix it

Comment: I do not know how to fix this error

Comment: match the min and max sdk version. I have no idea will it work

Answer (score 0):

```
 public GifView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, 
   int defStyleAttr) {
  super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
  init(context);
 }

 private void init(Context context){
  setFocusable(true);
  gifInputStream = context.getResources()
    .openRawResource(R.drawable.image);

  gifMovie = Movie.decodeStream(gifInputStream);
  movieWidth = gifMovie.width();
  movieHeight = gifMovie.height();
  movieDuration = gifMovie.duration();
 }
```